# create table query in oracle- ORA 00922

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a table in oracle 11g, that should be created only the first time, as in if it doesn't exist. If it exists it should not create the table.

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS sample_temp
(
    SFL_ID number(10) not null,
    STM_ID number(10) not null,
    FIL_ID number(10) not null,
    SYSTEM_GENERATED_FL char null    ,
    SFL_DELETE_FL char not null,
    SFL_VERSION_ID number(10) not null,
    PTN_ID number(10) not null);
```

This gives an ORA- 00922 error, telling a syntax error near the words "if not". What am I doing wrong? Is 'if not exists' not supported in Oracle? then how should I go about doing it? I am actually trying to create this via jdbc.

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find the `not exists` option?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[oracle]+create+table+if+not+exists

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support the `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax. The easiest solution would be to run another query to check whether table already exists in the schema of your database.

If you are connecting as a user `orcl`, and the table you are trying to create is going to be on the same schema, then you can do this

```
 select count(*) from user_tables where table_name=upper('yourtable');
```

if the count returns 1, then you know that the table exists and you can skip the table creation process. Otherwise go ahead and create the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "if not exists" command recheck if table already exists or not. You can do one thing : you can use query USER_TABLES or DBA_TABLES to check if your table exists or not .If it exists then do what you want to do and if it doesn't exists then you can create a new one .

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send the CREATE TABLE statement to the Oracle engine. If the table exists, this will return an error telling you the table already exists. If you need this for further processing in your code, you can just capture this error message.